# How to create a timeline with PHP MYSQL with data from my random selections according to the time?

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose there are 40 people on your web application and you are friends with only twenty of them. Each user has posted a photo and status update. How do you get the posts of the 20 people in your timeline all at once according to the time? What code will help?
What I did = 
i fetched list of my friends using while loop and fetched their updates again using the while loop.

```
$get_users = $con->query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE person1=$myid ");

while($rows=$get_users->fetch_assoc()){

$friendsid = $rows['person2'];

//this fetches 20 of my friends
//now what i did was fetching their updates using the WHILE loop again

$get_updates = $con->query("SELECT * FROM updates WHERE userid=$friendsid ");

    while($rows=$get_updates->fetch_assoc()){

    $updates_status = $rows['text'];
    $updates_photo = $rows['photo'];

echo " $update_status <br> $updates_photo <br> ";


    }
}
```

---

But the problem with this is, I always see the updates from my same friend first. Even if his update is 2 weeks old, it is shown at the very first whereas the 19th friend who updated his status just a minute ago is at the second last of the updates. 
How do I get the updates according to the time posted from only my friends?

Comment: `ORDER BY <your datetime field>`

Comment: Add an ORDER BY to your query to get the results in a certain order.

Comment: This will show the latest post of the first friend but it will not show the recent post of last friend posted after the first friend's post. What i really wana do is, show the post of the last person if it is the latest among the friend list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, use the code below:

```
$get_users = $con->query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE person1=$myid ");

$friends = '';

while($rows=$get_users->fetch_assoc())
{
   $friends .= $rows['person2'].',';
}


$get_updates = $con->query("SELECT * FROM updates WHERE userid IN ".substr($friends, 0, -1)." ORDER BY date"); //probably you have 'date' field

while($rows=$get_updates->fetch_assoc())
{

    $updates_status = $rows['text'];
    $updates_photo = $rows['photo'];

    echo " $update_status <br> $updates_photo <br> ";
}
```

Comment: Wow! I spent some time figuring things out and this is exactly what i needed. But i have to ask you something more about this.

Comment: It gives results like -> apple(data fetched) from 1(personid string) I want to hide the 'from 1 or from 2 ' text and  style each of of the personid.

Comment: I am really sorry for that misinformation. Your solution was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for that. And about that above comment, "it was just due to my own code which I could not locate. Now I have located it." Thank you for your help. <3

Comment: Ok. So, please, mark my answer as choosen solution :)

Comment: Although it's almost a year now. I did it. I didn't know how to mark an answer for a question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost there. All you have to do to retrieve the latest 20 posts, you need to sort the data by your `POST_TIME` column. Something like this:

```
$get_users = $con->query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE person1=$myid ");
while($rows=$get_users->fetch_assoc()){
    $friendsid = $rows['person2'];
    //this fetches 20 of my friends
    //now what i did was fetching their updates using the WHILE loop again

    $get_updates = $con->query("SELECT * FROM updates WHERE userid=$friendsid ORDER BY POST_TIME");

    while($rows=$get_updates->fetch_assoc()){
        $updates_status = $rows['text'];
        $updates_photo = $rows['photo'];

        echo " $update_status <br> $updates_photo <br> ";
    }
}
```

Change `POST_TIME` with the proper column name.